# How can I install R packages in newest version of R 4.2.3 image while building the image through docker file

Tags: r, r-package, docker-image, rstudio-server

I am trying to update and rebuild my RStudio image on centos with the docker file. Initially I was using R-3.6.0 which I am planning to update to R-4.3.1

Updated code snippet

```
RUN yum install -y java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel \
                   R-4.3.1 \    # Updated this line from R-3.6.0
                   devtoolset-8 --nogpgcheck && \
    yum install -y cmake3 \
                   ImageMagick-c++-devel \
                   proj \
                   proj-devel \
                   epel-release \
                   v8-devel

RUN echo /opt/R/4.3.1/bin/R --version && \
    chmod -R 755 /usr/lib64/R && \
    yum install -y /tmp/Rpackages/rstudio-server-rhel-2023.06.1-524-x86_64.rpm && \

# Install R packages
RUN /usr/bin/R CMD INSTALL /tmp/Rpackages/yaImpute_1.0-33.tar.gz        && \ -- This line throws  an error 
#    /usr/bin/R CMD INSTALL /tmp/Rpackages/ALEPlot_1.1.tar.gz            && \
```

After updating the R version in the above code While installing R packages it throws below error.

```
#0 0.260 /bin/sh: /usr/bin/R: No such file or directory
```

What path should I pass while installing packages on line `RUN /usr/bin/R CMD INSTALL /tmp/Rpackages/yaImpute_1.0-33.tar.gz` ?
Previously above code used to work for older version of R. is there any update in the path that I should mentioned?

Comment: Your first RUN command calls `/opt/bin/R/4.2.3/bin/R` yet your second RUN command calls  `/usr/bin/R`.  That is a slight disconnect.  You may need to either create a soft-link or update your second RUN command.  (And for completeness, "newest" R is 4.3.1.)

Comment: Hi Dirk, 

1. That echo line I was just trying to print the version. which is also not printing(may be my logs are suppressed). 

2. Yes I am using 4.3.1 version, updated code. I was trying few other latest version so the code was showing that version. 

3. I tried to link with  ln -s /opt/R/4.3.1/bin/R /usr/bin/R but there also it says  ln -s /opt/R/4.3.1/bin/R /usr/local/bin/R \